# How to get CLIENT_ID from a existing Instagram AccessToken

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I get AccessToken from client, and then passing to server. I need to check is that access token belong to my app not others.

Is there any way to get the CLIENT_ID from token, just like Facebook's debug token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not documented but as far as I tested the access token consists of 3 parts separated with dots while the second part is 7 characters matching the first 7 characters of the client_id of the app requesting the authentication:

> access_token: xxxxxxxxx.**yyyyyyy**.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
>
> client_id: yyyyyyy*************************
>
> user_id: xxxxxxxxx (first part of the access token)

Although it does not matter if the *access_token* generation was initiated by another application, because it is a privilege to access the Instagram API on behalf of the authenticated user and it will not affect your application.

Comment: Thanks :) I need this check because I'm afraid that if an app leak access tokens, then all token is valid on my app, any one get these tokens can directly log in to my app if I don't do this check. That's terrible!